# Help with Rinkeby "faucet offline" error, I'd appreciate some assstance :)

Tags: rinkeby

When minting an NFT via Manifold, I get "faucet offline" error when getting ETH from Rinkeby, I'd appreciate some assitance :)

0x4a6c649b5c6F7A6EfEa425fF3154a8bd0167F263

Answer (score 1):

For faucets you can try to use:

- https://rinkebyfaucet.com/
- https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine :) try this 
https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby

Answer (score 0):

I am using Chainlink faucet on Rinkeby test net, here is the link: https://faucets.chain.link/

Connect your wallet first, choose the test net you want and get it free in seconds.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can have 0.1 rinkeby ETH every 24 hours trough this link
https://rinkebyfaucet.com/

[image]